# How do you get underline font geometry from font? CreateFont

Tags: winapi, fonts, gdi+, gdi, truetype

I have a library that extracts the text geometry from a truetype font file.

I use a call to CreateFont to get hold of the glyph indices and then I read the bytestream to get the point data.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The issue is that if I pass true in the underline argument, The geometry does not contain the underline. 
Is there something specific that needs to be done??

The doc reads:
*fdwUnderline [in]
Specifies an underlined font if set to TRUE.*

This will help a lot!

Comment: Truetype fonts don't have separate underlined variants.  For example, when you select underlined Arial, Windows uses regular Arial and draws a line under it.  If you read the geometry from a ttf file you get the geometry without an underline, because that's what the file contains.

Comment: Hmm.. I thought so.. So the flag is only for the bitmap rendering.  thanks!

Comment: I've answered and added some further info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truetype fonts don't have separate underlined variants. For example, when you select underlined Arial, Windows uses regular Arial and draws a line under it. If you read the geometry from a ttf file you get the geometry without an underline, because that's what the file contains.

If you want the "as drawn" geometry, select an outline font and call [`BeginPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`TextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `EndPath` and `GetPath`.

Comment: You can use GetOutlineTextMetrics, which includes fields that tell you where the underscore should be drawn and how thick it should be.  Same answer applies to strike-through.